# Alternatives to apply same condition to multiple variables inside case_when function

Tags: r

I am trying to find a more efficient or elegant solution to multiple conditioning inside `case_when` function.

I am creating a dummy column based on multiple conditions across specific columns of a data frame. There are many cases where I use the same `is.na()` for many columns. I have the correct result, but I have tried other approaches with `apply`, `reduce` and `anyNa` without success.

Let's say this data frame looks like the data I'm working on:

```r
set.seed(12)
dframe <- data.frame(
  x1 = sample(letters[1:2], 10, replace = TRUE),
  x2 = sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE),
  x3 = sample(0:2, 10, replace = TRUE),
  x4 = sample(0:2, 10, replace = TRUE),
  x5 = sample(0:2, 10, replace = TRUE),
  x6 = sample(0:2, 10, replace = TRUE)
) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric, list(~na_if(., 2)))
```

And it looks like this:

```r
   x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6
1   b  1 NA  0  0  0
2   b  0  0  0 NA NA
3   b  1  0  0  0  1
4   a  0 NA  1 NA  0
5   a  1  1 NA NA NA
6   b  0 NA  1  1  1
7   a  1  1 NA NA  0
8   a  1  0  1 NA  0
9   b  1 NA NA  0  0
10  b  1  1  0 NA NA
```

Then, I create the column `x7` based on the following conditions:

```r
dframe %>% 
  mutate(
    x7 = case_when(
      x2 == 1 & 
      (!is.na(x3) | !is.na(x4) | !is.na(x5)) & 
      !is.na(x6) ~ 1,
      x2 == 1 ~ 0,
      TRUE ~ NA_real_
    )
  )
```

resulting in:

```r
   x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7
1   b  1 NA  0  0  0  1
2   b  0  0  0 NA NA NA
3   b  1  0  0  0  1  1
4   a  0 NA  1 NA  0 NA
5   a  1  1 NA NA NA  0
6   b  0 NA  1  1  1 NA
7   a  1  1 NA NA  0  1
8   a  1  0  1 NA  0  1
9   b  1 NA NA  0  0  1
10  b  1  1  0 NA NA  0
```

However, I want to find an alternative to write `(!is.na(x3) | !is.na(x4) | !is.na(x5))` because in my real script I have to type this for 11 columns.

I've tried to use `complete.cases(x3, x4, x5)`, but it doesn't follow the logic I'm using in the code.

Using `anyNA(x3, x4, x5)` throws `Error in anyNA(x3, x4, x5) : anyNA takes 1 or 2 arguments`.

Also tried the answers of a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49013683/filter-multiple-columns-based-on-same-criteria-in-r), but since I'm not using it for filtering, it didn't work out.

Maybe I'm overthinking it, but what I'm looking for is something without having to use `(!is.na(x3) | !is.na(x4) | !is.na(x5))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `rowSums` and specify the columns by name

```
library(dplyr)

dframe %>% 
  mutate(x7 = case_when(
               x2 == 1 & 
               rowSums(!is.na(.[c("x3","x4","x5")])) > 0 &
               !is.na(x6) ~ 1,
               x2 == 1 ~ 0,
               TRUE ~ NA_real_
              )
          )
```

Or by position

```
rowSums(!is.na(.[3:5])) > 0
```

---

We could do this using inverted logic as well.

```
rowSums(is.na(.[c("x3","x4","x5")])) != 3
```

Or

```
rowSums(is.na(.[3:5])) != 3
```

We use 3 here as there are 3 columns to check in the given example (`x3`, `x4` and `x5`), you can change the number based on your actual number of columns (11).

Comment: That's it! I prefer naming the columns, but every option works wonders. It seems so obvious now. Thanks for the help!